# How do i make adjacency Matrix with the given data

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, adjacency-matrix

I have a gene interaction data like down below. Any idea how to make an adjacency matrix from this data?

[image: this data have 3 columns and 66k rows, and have about 5k unique values]

Comment: See bottom example with crosstab https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Answer (score 1):

Example data:

```
cat_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(list("abcdef"))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "node1":["a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "f"],
        "node2":["b", "d", "c", "e", "f", "e"],
    }
).astype(cat_type)
```

`df` looks like this:

```
  node1 node2
0     a     b
1     b     d
2     a     c
3     c     e
4     b     f
5     f     e
```

Solution

```
adj_mat = pd.crosstab(df["node1"], df["node2"], dropna=False)
```

results in a dataframe:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f
a  0  1  1  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  1  0  1
c  0  0  0  0  1  0
d  0  0  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  0  0  0  0
f  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

If you need it symmetrical around the diagonal then the following will give you a boolean result

```
adj_mat.transpose() + adj_mat > 0
```

which you can then convert to integer with `.astype(int)` if required